# Android: I want to swipe between cells of a grid where only one cell is visible at a time

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview, android-gridview

I want a single cell of a grid to take up my whole screen and swipe up/down/left/right to access other cells (not smoothly, but switch to the next cell). What do you think is a good way of implementing this?

I've partially implemented this in GridView and ListView containing a HorizontalListView and am considering TableLayout.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the [DirectionalViewPager on github](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager/) and try to modify it so that it can always swipe in any direction instead of having to call `setOrientation(DirectionalViewPager.VERTICAL)`and `setOrientation(DirectionalViewPager.HORIZONTAL)` I don't know exactly how much you'll have to modify it, but it is most of the way there, I would think that the change should be relatively straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

How about you take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html). the horizontal paging(swipe views)